# SQlite Query to get Multiple value from same Column by passing CheckBox selected items

Tags: android, sqlite, checkbox, android-recyclerview

I have populated **RecyclerView with CheckBox**. When I click "**APPLY**" button ,I have gotten all the clicked check box value(**CATEGORY**). I need to get relevant data by passing this category in SQLite.

I have done it by selecting only one Category. But I need to get the relevant data of selected Category form the DataBase.

From the Image,

I need to get the relevant data of Bakery,Bowl,Box from the SQlite dataBase.

For getting only one selected item,I used the following Query:

```
public Cursor getProductDetail(String strCategoryID) {
    return db.query(DbHelper.MY_PRODUCT_TABLE, MY_PRODUCTLIST_FIELDS,
            DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_ID + "='" + strCategoryID+ "'", null, null,
            null, null);
}
```

[image]

How to do this? Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Done the things by the following:

```
public Cursor getCategoryFilter(ArrayList<String> categoryFilterId) {

    String abc = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < categoryFilterId.size(); i++) {
        if (abc.equals(""))
            abc += DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_ID + "='" + categoryFilterId.get(i) + "'";
        else
            abc += " OR " + DbHelper.JSON_CATEGORY_ID + "='" + categoryFilterId.get(i) + "'";
    }

    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.MY_PRODUCT_TABLE + " WHERE " + abc, null);
    return cur;
}
```